# Is there any constraint where to add the subpass dependency?

Tags: vulkan

I have the following setup: One renderpass draws to a texture and the second renderpass draws to a different texture and reads the first one.

To avoid artifacts I added a subpass dependency to the first render pass:
(C# SharpVulkan like code)

```
SubpassDependency subpassDependency = new SubpassDependency()
{
    SourceSubpass = 0,
    DestinationSubpass = (~0U),//aka VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL
    SourceAccessMask = AccessFlags.ColorAttachmentWrite,
    SourceStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.ColorAttachmentOutput,
    DestinationAccessMask = AccessFlags.ShaderRead,
    DestinationStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.FragmentShader,
    DependencyFlags = DependencyFlags.ByRegion,
};
```

This expresses the dependency "The fragment shader of the following renderpass waits until the current render pass finished rendering."

If I try to model the same dependency the other way around "The fragment shader of the current render pass waits until the previous render pass finished rendering" the synchronization fails and I have artifacts in the final image.

```
SubpassDependency subpassDependency = new SubpassDependency()
{
    SourceSubpass = (~0U),//VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    DestinationSubpass = 0,
    SourceAccessMask = AccessFlags.ColorAttachmentWrite,
    SourceStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.ColorAttachmentOutput,
    DestinationAccessMask = AccessFlags.ShaderRead,
    DestinationStageMask = PipelineStageFlags.FragmentShader,
    DependencyFlags = DependencyFlags.ByRegion,
};
```

Quote from the specification:

> If srcSubpass is equal to VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, the first synchronization scope includes commands submitted to the queue before the render pass instance began.

I dont understand why the second approach is not working and what are the constraints for the subpass dependency to work. Is there something in the specification I missed ?

Comment: Vulkan is big and complicated. There could be many reasons why what you did didn't work besides the way you set up your subpass dependencies. Turn on some validation layers.

Comment: Validation layers are already on and report no errors. If the dependency is added to the first render pass everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you skip the external dependency in the first renderpass, then a default one is provided. It has `dstStageMask` of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT`. The automatic transfer to the `finalLayout` is only guaranteed to happen-before the visibility operation of the external dependency (so, before `BOTTOM_OF_PIPE`).

In the second renderpass you specify `srcStageMask` of `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, so I would think there is a race condition between the transfer to `finalLayout` and first use in the second renderpass.

Comment: That makes sense. For some reason I believed that the implicit dependency was added in the command buffer execution.

[Specification about implicit subpass dependencies](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#renderpass-creation)